# Suggestions for the format of text quoted

Tags: quoting

I am looking for the best form to quote  external text from other authors, but with my version I am unhappy, cause --in my point of view-- it is poor and less visual than I liked to.

This is my definition, that I put on the preamble of the document:

```
\def\cita{\advance\leftskip 2cm\advance\rightskip 1cm \sffamily \scriptsize}
```

When I want to cite text, I put this:

```
{\cita
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec elit dictum, mattis nibh in, aliquam nibh. Nullam varius lobortis condimentum. Quisque vel felis est. Mauris id tincidunt lacus, quis lobortis neque. Sed pretium placerat lorem eget ullamcorper. Curabitur ac turpis diam. Duis et tempor turpis, non luctus arcu.
\par}
```

which produces this type of output:

[image]

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Please provide some more information as to *what exactly* you dislike about the look of the macro you've come up with. Do you dislike the amount of left-hand-side and right-hand-side indentation, are you unhappy about the use of a sans-serif font, are you dissatisfied with the 30% liner reduction in font size induced by the instruction `\scriptsize` -- or is it something else altogether?

Comment: Do you know about package `csquotes`? It provides you with environments and macros to cite blocks of text and more.

Comment: If you desire your quotes to have quotation marks that "protrude" from the quote block, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166173/hanging-punctuation-with-quotation-marks-in-left-margin

Comment: My problem is my poor implementacion. I was thinking in the cited text that we can see in magazines, more colourful and amazing.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the `quote`-environment which should be part of any basic LaTeX-distribution?