# Blockquote mark indentation

Tags: indentation, quoting, csquotes

I would like to set the opening quotes just outside the quote margin.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry} \setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}

\begin{document}
    \noindent Die vorliegende Bachelorarbeit mit dem Titel
    \begin{quote}
        \noindent \enquote{Test und Evaluierung von Designkriterien für lasergeschmolzene Titanteile im SLM-Prozess unter Verwendung von Heitzelementen}
    \end{quote}
    \noindent beinhaltet interne und vertrauliche Informationen des Unternehmens \textsc{Corporation}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Kerning: Manual adjustment of `\noindent\kern-0.56em\enquote{` will do it. I think a Tikz solution would be more flexible (font, size, colour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting my answer at [Hanging punctuation with quotation marks in left margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166173/hanging-punctuation-with-quotation-marks-in-left-margin/166182#166182), I introduce the `quoted` environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[babel, german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry} \setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}
\def\andIquote{\makebox[0pt][r]{\guillemotright}}
\newenvironment{quoted}
{\quote\andIquote\ignorespaces}{\unskip\guillemotleft\endquote}

\begin{document}
    \noindent Die vorliegende Bachelorarbeit mit dem Titel
    \begin{quoted}
        \noindent Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR
    \end{quoted}
    \noindent beinhaltet interne und vertrauliche Informationen des Unternehmens \textsc{Corporation}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Experiment (and logic) indicate a quotation mark to the left of a box would be the likeliest type of solution.

Example 4a possibly comes closest to requirements, but none is fully satisfactory.

Interestingly, `\enquote` can enquote a box.

Tikz is proving a bit trickier to handle in terms of `xshift`.

[image: quoted block]

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry} \setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\qtype[1]{{\color{blue}(#1)}}
\newcommand\sep{\begin{center} *\end{center}}

\begin{document}

%==================== 1
    \noindent [1] \qtype{enquote+mp} Die vorliegende Bachelorarbeit mit dem Titel
\medskip

%\begin{center}
\hspace{5em}{\huge
\enquote{{\normalsize%
%\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \noindent Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR
\end{minipage}
%}%fbox
}}
}
%\end{center}
\medskip

    \noindent beinhaltet interne und vertrauliche Informationen des Unternehmens \textsc{Corporation}.
\sep

%==================== 2
\bigskip

\noindent [2] \qtype{3-cell tabular+mp} Die vorliegende Bachelorarbeit mit dem Titel
\medskip


\hspace{5em}\begin{tabular}{r|c|l}
\huge »&
    %\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \noindent Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR
\end{minipage}
%}
& \huge «\\
\end{tabular}
\medskip

    \noindent beinhaltet interne und vertrauliche Informationen des Unternehmens \textsc{Corporation}.
\sep

%==================== 3
\bigskip

\noindent [3] \qtype{tikz+mp} Die vorliegende Bachelorarbeit mit dem Titel
\medskip

    %\fbox{%
%\begin{quote}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\noindent\tikz\node[xshift=-3em](a){\Large »};
Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR
\end{minipage}
\tikz\node[xshift=1em,yshift=4em](b){\Large «};
%\end{quote}
%}


\medskip

    \noindent beinhaltet interne und vertrauliche Informationen des Unternehmens \textsc{Corporation}.
\sep

%==================== 4
\bigskip

\noindent [4] \qtype{3-cell tabular+mp+makecell} Die vorliegende Bachelorarbeit mit dem Titel
%\medskip


\hspace{5em}\begin{tabular}{rcl}
\huge »&
    %\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \noindent Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR
\end{minipage}
%}
& \makecell{\\ \\\\\\\huge «}\\
\end{tabular}
\medskip

    \noindent beinhaltet interne und vertrauliche Informationen des Unternehmens \textsc{Corporation}.
\sep

%==================== 4
\bigskip

\noindent [4a] \qtype{1-cell tabular+mp} Die vorliegende Bachelorarbeit mit dem Titel
\medskip


%\enquote{%
\hspace{5em}\begin{tabular}{c}
    %\fbox{%
{\huge »}    
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \noindent Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR
{\huge «}\end{minipage}
%}
\end{tabular}
%}
\medskip

    \noindent beinhaltet interne und vertrauliche Informationen des Unternehmens \textsc{Corporation}.
\sep

\end{document}
```

---

For reference, the manual kerning method

```
    \begin{quote}
        \noindent\kern-0.56em\enquote{Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR}
    \end{quote}
```

give this:

[image: manual kerning]

---

**Addendum**

Example (3a).

For the Tikz solution path, an inline 3-node tikzpicture, instead of a tikz-ed blockquote, seems to work better (with some manual adjustment of the node positions - with `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`)

[image: all tikz]

Code snippet:

```
\noindent [3a] \qtype{all tikz} 
Die vorliegende Bachelorarbeit mit dem Titel
\medskip


\noindent\hspace{5em}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 1mm and 1mm,
 ]
\node (a){\Large »};
\node[yshift=-3ex, xshift=-0.8em,right=of a, text width=0.5\textwidth](b){%
Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR
};
\node[yshift=-2.5ex, xshift=-1.6em,right=of b] (c){\Large «};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

There are likely more elegant methods.