# How to use \openautoquote that must not be in a env in a env?

Tags: indentation, typography, quoting, csquotes

I was trying to improve [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166213/98645) to make it fully compatible with `csquotes`.

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% hanging indentation for quotes, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166213/98645
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\strut\llap{``}}
% #1 is closing punctuation, #2 is citation. 
% We don't use them in this instance, but they
% need to be "catered for"
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}[2]{#1''\ifblank{#2}{}{#2}}
% #1 is closing punctuation, #2 is citation.
% again, we provide for them if needed

\begin{document}
\begin{displayquote}
Now we use an \enquote{quote inside the quote} in this
long text.\\
Bear with me.
\end{displayquote}

\end{document}
```

The **problems** there are:

1. The quotation marks are now again statically defined – which goes against the aim of `csquotes`. You can fix this by replacing them above, e.g. in German you'd use `,,`  instead of the ``` `` ``` in `\mkbegdispquote`, but this is still not flexible then.
2. Worse, it breaks `csquotes` actual intended mechanism for **nested quotations**.
   In the above example “quote inside the quote“ will be typesetted wrong and use *outer quotation marks* (“”), instead of *inner* ones (‘’) as it is supposed to do.

### Tries to fix

Looking at the [csquotes doc](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf) I've tried to fix this:

```
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\strut\llap{\openautoquote}}
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}[2]{#1\closeautoquote\ifblank{#2}{}{#2}}
```

That would have been too easy, would not it?
The problem seems to be, `\openautoquote` does not work and thinks it is unbalanced, if it is in a "environment" (please bear with me if this is the wrong term, I don't know the LaTeX internals), i.e. in `\llap`.
My next idea then was to "fake" this, display an ordinary symbol and hide the one that just says `csquotes` that it should count a nesting in it's quotation order.

```
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\strut\llap{\textooquote}\vphantom{\openautoquote}}
```

Well… it's still in `\vphantom` now, so of course it still does not work.
I have also seen no way in `csquotes` to manually adjust the nesting *without* displaying the actual sign.

So how can I do that?

Problem one above is effectively fixed, just the second one is my problem here.

Comment: Note: I also noticed you can of course manually use `\enquote*` (the starred version) inside of the quote to force the quotes correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also an init command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\leavevmode\llap{\textooquote}\initoquote}
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}[2]{#1\textcoquote\ifblank{#2}{}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{displayquote}
Now we use an \enquote{quote inside the quote} in this
long text.\\
Bear with me.
\end{displayquote}

\selectlanguage{french}
\begin{displayquote}
Now we use an \enquote{quote inside the quote} in this
long text.\\
Bear with me.
\end{displayquote}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\begin{displayquote}
Now we use an \enquote{quote inside the quote} in this
long text.\\
Bear with me.
\end{displayquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And while we are at it, `csquotes` provides a `foreigndisplayquote` environment, which includes the babel language selection. So you may want to use this instead of `\selectlanguage`.